# How to Add Multiline Text Tooltips in Bar Chart D3 JS

Tags: html, css, d3.js, svg

I am looking a way how to add multiline text in one box tooltips using d3.v3.min.js . My illustration behavior like this :

[image]

And the code that I made is like this :

**HTML**, **CSS**, **Javascript**

```js
function responsivefy(svg) {
    // get container + svg aspect ratio
    var container = d3.select(svg.node().parentNode),
        width = parseInt(svg.style("width")),
        height = parseInt(svg.style("height")),
        aspect = width / height;

    // add viewBox and preserveAspectRatio properties,
    // and call resize so that svg resizes on inital page load
    svg.attr("viewBox", "0 0 " + width + " " + height)
        .attr("perserveAspectRatio", "xMinYMid")
        .call(resize);

    d3.select(window).on("resize." + container.attr("id"), resize);

    // get width of container and resize svg to fit it
    function resize() {
        var targetWidth = parseInt(container.style("width"));
        svg.attr("height", Math.round(targetWidth / aspect));
        svg.attr("width", targetWidth);
    }
}

var arrData = [
    {"category":"Diversity & Inlusion 1", "actual":4.2, "target":5, "prediction":40, "skala":"20%"},
    {"category":"Image 1", "actual":4.5, "target":4.2,"prediction":60, "skala":"40%"},
    {"category":"Image 2", "actual":4.1, "target":4,"prediction":80, "skala":"60%"},
    {"category":"Job Security 1", "actual":4.4, "target":4.3,"prediction":60, "skala":"100%"},
    {"category":"Job Security 2", "actual":4.4, "target":4.3,"prediction":40, "skala":"100%"},
    {"category":"Job Security 3", "actual":4.4, "target":4.3,"prediction":20, "skala":"100%"},
    {"category":"Image 3", "actual":4.4, "target":4.3,"prediction":10, "skala":"100%"},
    {"category":"Diversity & Inlusion 2", "actual":4.4, "target":4.3,"prediction":30, "skala":"100%"},
    {"category":"Values", "actual":4.4, "target":4.3,"prediction":75, "skala":"100%"},
    {"category":"Collaboration", "actual":4.4, "target":4.3,"prediction":45, "skala":"100%"}
];

//console.log(arrData);

//set up svg using margin conventions - we'll need plenty of room on the left for labels
var margin = {
    top: 15, right: 95, bottom: 15, left: 60
};

var marginBar2 = {
    top:10
};

var width = 650 - margin.left - margin.right;
var height = 768 - margin.top - margin.bottom;
var svgColor = "white";
var barHeight = 200;
  
//Create Main SVG
var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
    .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
    .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
    .style("background-color", svgColor);
    // .call(responsivefy);

//Create xScale and yScale
var xScale1 = d3.scale.linear()
    .range([0, width * 0.70])
    .domain([0, d3.max(arrData, function (d) {
        return d.prediction;
    })]);

var xScale2 = d3.scale.linear()
    .range([0, width * 0.70])
    .domain([0, d3.max(arrData, function (d) {
        return d.target;
    })]);

var xScale3 = d3.scale.ordinal()
    .rangeRoundBands([0, width * 0.93])
    .domain(arrData.map(function (d) {
        return d.skala;
    }));

var yScale = d3.scale.ordinal()
    .rangeRoundBands([0, height])
    .domain(arrData.map(function (d) {
        return d.category;
    }));

//Make yAxis to Show Category
var yAxis = d3.svg.axis()
    .scale(yScale)
    .tickSize(0)
    .orient("left");

var gyAxis = svg.append("g")
    //.attr("class", "y axis")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + width * 0.35   + "," + height * 0 + ")")
    .style("text-anchor", "start")
    .style("font-size", 12)
    .style("font-weight", "bold")
    .style("fill", "#212121")
    .call(yAxis);

//Make xAxis to Show Category
// var xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
//     .scale(xScale3)
//     .tickSize(5)
//     .orient("bottom");

// var gxAxis = svg.append("g")
//     .attr("class", "x axis")
//     .style("font-size", 14)
//     .style("font-weight", "bold")
//     .style("fill", "#212121")
//     .attr("transform", "translate(" + width * 0.385  + "," + height * 1 + ")")
//     .call(xAxis);

var bars1 = svg.selectAll(".bar")
    .data(arrData).enter()
    .append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + width * 0.50  + "," + 0 + ")");

bars1.append("rect")
    .attr("class", "bar")
    .attr("y", function (d) {
        return yScale(d.category);
    })
    .attr("height", barHeight - 140)
    .attr("x", 0)
    // .style("fill", "#c0c0c0")
    .attr("width", function(d){
        return xScale2(d.target);
    })
    .on("mouseover", function(){
        tooltip1.style("display", null);
    })
    .on("mouseout", function(){
        tooltip1.style("display", "none");
    })
    .on("mousemove", function(d){
        var xPos = d3.mouse(this)[0] - 10;
        var yPos = d3.mouse(this)[1] - 15;
        tooltip1.attr("transform", "translate(" + xPos + "," + yPos +")");
        tooltip1.selectAll("text").text("DI4");
        tooltip1.selectAll("rect")
            .attr("width", 250)
            .attr("width", (function(d) {
                return this.parentNode.getBBox().width;
            }));
    });

var bars2 = svg.selectAll(".bar2nd")
    .data(arrData).enter()
    .append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + width * 0.50 + "," + marginBar2.top  + ")");

bars2.append("rect")
    .attr("class", "bar2nd")
    .attr("y", function (d) {
        return yScale(d.category);
    })
    .attr("height", barHeight - 160)
    .attr("x", 0)
    .attr("width", function (d) {
        return xScale1(d.prediction);
    })
    .on("mouseover", function(){
        tooltip2.style("display", null);
    })
    .on("mouseout", function(){
        tooltip2.style("display", "none");
    })
    .on("mousemove", function(d){
        var xPos = d3.mouse(this)[0] - 10;
        var yPos = d3.mouse(this)[1] - 15;
        tooltip2.attr("transform", "translate(" + xPos + "," + yPos +")");
        tooltip2.selectAll("text").html("DI3");
        tooltip2.selectAll("rect")
            .attr("width", 250)
            .attr("width", (function(d) {
                return this.parentNode.getBBox().width;
            }));
    });

var barValue1 = svg.selectAll(".barValue1")
    .data(arrData).enter()
    .append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + width * 0.40 + "," + height * 0.055 + ")");

barValue1.append("text")
    .attr("class", "barValue1")
    .attr("y", function (d) {
        return yScale(d.category);
    })
    .attr("x", 0)
    .style("font-size", 18)
    .style("font-weight", "bold")
    .style("fill", "#212121")
    .html(function(d){
        return d3.format(",.2r")(d.actual);
    });

var barValue2 = svg.selectAll(".barValue2")
    .data(arrData).enter()
    .append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + width * 0.51 + "," + height * 0.055 + ")");

barValue2.append("text")
    .attr("class", "barValue2")
    .attr("y", function (d) {
        return yScale(d.category);
    })
    .attr("x", 0)
    .style("font-size", 18)
    // .style("font-weight", "bold")
    .style("fill", "white")
    .text(function(d){
        return d3.format(".2%")(d.prediction / 100);
    });

var tooltip1 = svg.selectAll("g.tooltip1")
    .data(arrData)
    .enter()
    .append("g")
    .attr("class", "tooltip")
    .style("display", "none");

tooltip1.append("rect")
    // .attr("width", width * 0.7)
    .attr("height", height * 0.2)
    .style("fill", "white")
    .style("stroke", "#969696")
    .attr("stroke-width",1)
    .style("opacity", 1);

tooltip1.append("text")
    .attr("id", "txt1")
    .attr("x", width * 0.05)
    .attr("dy", height * 0.05)
    .attr("font-size", 18)
    .attr("font-weight", "bold");

var tooltip2 = svg.selectAll("g.tooltip1")
    .data(arrData)
    .enter()
    .append("g")
    .attr("class", "tooltip")
    .style("display", "none");

tooltip2.append("rect")
    // .attr("width", width * 0.7)
    .attr("height", height * 0.2)
    .style("fill", "white")
    .style("stroke", "#969696")
    .attr("stroke-width",1)
    .style("opacity", 1);

tooltip2.append("text")
    .attr("id", "txt1")
    .attr("x", width * 0.05)
    .attr("dy", height * 0.05)
    .attr("font-size", 18)
    .attr("font-weight", "bold");
```

```css
body{
    font-family: "Arial", sans-serif;
}
.bar{
    fill: #c0c0c0;
}
.bar:hover{
    fill:rgb(95, 109, 148);
}
.bar2nd{
    fill:#00315b;
}
.bar2nd:hover{
    fill:#3e73b8;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.5.17/d3.min.js"></script>
```

is there anyone could help about my problem ? cause I need to get the code for multiline text inside tooltips box.

Answer (score 3):

It might be more straightforward to append the tooltips using divs rather than svg rects - for instance, if you added:

```
var tooltip = d3.select("body").append("div")
    .attr("class", "tooltip")
.style("opacity", 0);
```

Into your code, then you could make it appear and disappear plus add multi-line text using:

```
.on("mouseover", function(d){
        var xPos = d3.mouse(this)[0];
        var yPos = d3.mouse(this)[1];
        tooltip.style("left", xPos + "px")
                .style("top", yPos + "px")
            .html("<p class='tooltip'>" + d.category + "<br><br>Line 2<br><br>Etc</p>")
            .transition().delay(200).style("opacity", 0.9);
    })
    .on("mouseout", function(){
       tooltip.transition().delay(0).style("opacity", 0);
    })
```

You can add the same styling you had before using CSS properties, as below:

```
div.tooltip {
    width: 200px;
    height: 125px;
    background-color: white;
    border: 1px solid #969696;
    position: absolute;
}

p.tooltip {
    font-size: 18;
    font-weight: 1em;
    padding-left: 10px;
}
```

I've mocked this up in a JSFiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/Glorificus/w6zfhc9e/2/) - it might have some of your code missing, apologies if so - but it should give a good idea how to merge it in if you want to use the code. Let me know if you have any questions! You should be able to get some more information from [here](https://bl.ocks.org/d3noob/a22c42db65eb00d4e369) if you need it too.

Comment: wow that is great friend. very helping for me. Yeah it must be missing the code. I thought with d3.v3.min.js is not working to declare .html inside the tooltip. Thanks friend.